# pbsnodes and bash string matching

Tags: string, bash, pbs

I have a string of the form: "8, 14-24, 30-45, 9", which is a substring of the output of pbsnodes.  This shows the cores in use on a given node, where 14-24 is a range of cores in use.

I'd like to know the total number of cores in use from this string, i.e. 
1 + (24 - 14 + 1) + (45 - 30 + 1 )+ 1 in this example, using a bash script.

Any suggestions or help is much appreciated.

Michael

Comment: What did you try to solve this?

Comment: unfortunately my bash is limited.  I know what'd I'd like to do: find each hyphen, set a as the integer in front based on the white space, b as the integer behind.  Take b-a-1 and add this to a processor count and then remove ", a - b" from the string.  Repeat until: "a,b,c".  Add these final ints to the count.  IFS as ":" and read seem to be useful, but maybe you have better suggestions?

Comment: Mike: these are good attempts, kindly update the question with these efforts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use pure `bash` techniques to achieve this. By reading the string to array and doing the arithmetic operator using the `$((..))` operator. You can run these commands directly on the command-line,

```
IFS=", " read -ra numArray <<<"8, 14-24, 30-45, 9"

unset count
for word in "${numArray[@]}"; do
   (( ${#word} == 1 )) && ((++count)) || count=$(( count +  ${word#*-} - ${word%-*} + 1  ))
done

printf "%s\n" "$count"
```

The idea is

- The `read` with `-a` splits the string on the de-limiter set by `IFS` and reads it into the array `numArray`
- A loop on each of the elements, for each element, if the element is just single character, just increment total count by `1`
- For numeric ranges, do manipulation as e.g. for number `a-b` use *parameter expansion* syntax `${word#*-}` and `${word%-*}` to extract `b` and `a` respectively and do `b-a+1` and add it with `count` calculated already and print the element after the loop
- You can put this in a `bash` script with she-bang set to `#!/bin/bash` and run the script or run it directly from the command-line

Comment: Great! Thanks! I'm out at the minute, but will check it out soon.

Comment: works like a treat.  Small mistake, on my part, in that it should be b-a +1, not -1.  I've edited this in the original question.  The ideal stack overflow answer.